# High Traffic Database Read/Write Error PHP Laravel Aurora

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

So we have a laravel 5 php app which read/write into an AWS Aurora DB around 1500-2000 times a minute. It is doing a simple select then update a value in a column.

However we are getting some errors when trying to update the value from time to time. (1 in 500 will error)

```
[2015-11-13 09:15:00] live.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message 'Call to a member function update() on null
```

This is our code

```
// Get the first free token sorted by the biggest ID to the smallest.
$token = TokenModel::where('expire_at', '>', Carbon::now())
            ->where('status', 'Free')
            ->orderBy('id', 'DESC')
            ->lockForUpdate()
            ->first();

// Update the status of the token.
$token->update(['status' => 'Used']);
```

We have tried removing/adding `lockForUpdate()` however this doesn't solve the problem.

Has anyone ever come across this issue before?

Updates:

```
    $token = null;

    while ($token == null) {
        // Get the first free token sorted by the biggest ID to the smallest.
        $token = TokenModel::where('expire_at', '>', Carbon::now())
            ->where('status', 'Free')
            ->orderBy('id', 'DESC')
            ->lockForUpdate()
            ->first();
    }
```

Comment: Have you considered that sometimes there are no entries that match the conditions of your query? The Query Builder's [`first`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.1/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php#L1368) method will return `null` when there are no matching entries. You should perhaps do a check that verifies that a result has actually been returned from the database. A simple condition like `if (!is_null($token)) { ... }` should suffice to check if an update is actually in order.

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion. I updated my code as follow to see if I can remove those errors

Comment: Tony, as a side note, I just moved a large Laravel project off Aurora back to vanilla MySQL RDS as I was having strange performance issues and intermittently not getting results back from queries. If you run into any performance issues I would encourage you to test the same.